# Does Text-To-Speech software read HTML comments?

Tags: html, text-to-speech

I want to comment out some items from an HTML pricelist but will visually impaired people still see those items or not (without inspecting the code of course)?
I would like for them not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessibility readers generally try to output only visible content. If your HTML is hidden (`display: none`, or commented out with `<!-- -->` XML comments) then readers won't read them. It's only if you make content invisible using CSS (like `opacity: 0` or `font-size: 0`) that the reader may still read the content.

If you want to explicitly mark content as hidden to screen readers use the [`aria-hidden="true"` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute).